# Wordpress Pagination Second Pagination pages goes blank with correct URL

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I need to paginate news category. But only first page is seen correct but when clicked on second page url shows correct but blank page is seen. I've checked almost every single posts of stack related to similar problem but couldn't figure out what is causing error. So please don't figure it as duplicate entry. Almost frustrated and exhausted seeking whole day. So I've pasted all my code. Here goes my code. Hope for a relief.

```
<?php
 if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
     $paged = get_query_var('paged');
 } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { 
     $paged = get_query_var('page');
 } else {
     $paged = 1;
 }

 $cquery = new WP_Query(array(
   'post_type' => 'news',
   'paged' => $paged,
   'posts_per_page' => 5
 ));

 if ($cquery->have_posts () ) :
 $i = 1;
 while ($cquery->have_posts () ) :
 $cquery->the_post();
  if($i > 0) :
?>
<!-- Other Stuff code goes here -->

<?php 
 endif; $i++; 
 endwhile; 
 endif;
?>
<?php if ($cquery->max_num_pages > 1) :   
  $orig_query = $wp_query; 
  $wp_query = $cquery;
  global $wp_query;
  $big = 999999999;
?>
<ul class="pagination">
  <li>
   <?php
     echo paginate_links( array(
         'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
         'format' => '?paged=%#%',
         'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
         'total' => $cquery->max_num_pages,
         'prev_text'          => __('« Previous'),
         'next_text'          => __('Next »'),
     ) );
     $wp_query = $orig_query; 
   ?>
  </li>
</ul>
<?php endif;  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Are you getting $paged variable correct on page 2? Please try to print get_query_var('paged') and check on second page

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be the issue. Just tested it in a local test site and it works just fine. is there anything that by any chance changes the $i to 0 causing the loop to just skip.

Comment: Problem is queries are not passing to second page. What could be done in this case??